# Display products in a Table format

Tags: product, layout, product-list

I would like to display my products in a table format on my sub-category page. Currently the products are by default populated either in a grid view or a list view.

All I want to do is to display products in a table format something like this

Columns: No.,   SKU,   Product Title,   Quantity,   Add to Cart Button

and each row will be the product belonging to the sub category.

Basically want to change the design of the grid/list layout to Table Layout

Answer (score 2):

You can make the change by editing the following file:

`app/design/frontend/theme/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`.

The `list.phtml` file contains the code which manages the display for both list & grid view.

You should see something along these lines, separating the two views:

```
<?php // List mode ?>
...
<?php // Grid Mode ?>
```

Simply make the design changes using HTML and you'll be all sorted.